# Cannot open a DLL file in visual studio 2015 Managed unit test Project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, linker-errors

When I edit and running the Manged unit test in Visual Studio 2015 It shows

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

Error LNK1104   cannot open file 'C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\Drop\x64\Test\DefaultTest.dll' 

XXXX_MDM_Test   C:\XXX\XXX\XXX\Test\xxx_MDM_Test\LINK   1
```

Points:-

1.My hard disk contain enough space

2.DefaultTest.dll file have read and write permissions

3.File Exists in my system

4.When i got this error If i restart the visual studio 2015 its working , again any changes in my source code This error automatically comes and again i have to restart my visual studio 2015.

5.The Process engine  halting the my .dll file

Please give me any solution..

Comment: The DLL is loaded into some process (probably the testing process).  The file is locked if it is loaded into a process.  Restarting VS is clearing the lock.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, My problem is even changing a small piece of code this DLL error coming, again and again. I frustrated with so many times restarting the visual studio, so much time wasting on this process, So I asked in this forum.

Comment: A question like this needs to document the installed anti-malware product.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't understand your words, I am facing this problem every time when changing the code in my Visual studio2015 Managed Test Project. That's why I asked.

Comment: Is there any way to rectify this issue permanently.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a project which was written with VS2012, And I got the dll error, I managed to solve it by going to properties of my test project Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories. edit this to location of your dll file.